# Including in progress but invited publications in resume and/or CV

Tags: publications, cv, invited-paper

I'm a co-author on two papers that were just recently submitted for publication. There seems to be a consensus that if you even include "in progress" papers, you should not include the journal they have been submitted to since they haven't been accepted by that journal. I was wondering if this is still the case for papers that are invited contributions to special issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people mentioning the 'under review' and 'in preparation' papers in their CV in the following way.

```
A. Author1, B. Author2, "The preparation of CV for a job" (under review)

A. Author1, B. Author2, "The preparation of CV for a job" (In preparation)
```

However, it does not add much value it the quantitative weight of CV except that people would know that your are active in your research.

If you are invited to submit an article, then you could mention like this:

```
A. Author1, B. Author2, "The preparation of CV for a job" (In preparation; invited for 
special issue on Imagination)
```